# updating the observable collection of a view model from another helper class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

i have a ViewModel with an ObservableCollection, i have a long function that i will use to update the ObservableCollection items however the function is so long and i don't want to put it inside the ViewModel.

i want to do the updates directly on the ObservableCollection so that i can see the changes on my view while the process is running.

i thought about the followig

- sending the ObservableCollection by ref
- sending the current item to a function and return the updated
  object
- making my ObservableCollection static
- puting the update function in my ViewModel but that will make my ViewModel big and messy

there will be alot of different functions that will work on this collection, in such cases what is the best programing practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are processing the data and then passing the processed data to the View then I think the below option should be one possible solution.

The below solution will process the data while the view is also notified of the change simultaneously.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _unprocessedData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> _processedData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private static object _lock = new object();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get { return _processedData; } }//Bind the view to this property

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        //Populate the data in _unprocessedData
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_processedData, _lock); //this will ensure the data between the View and VM is not corrupted
        ProcessData();
    }

    private async void ProcessData()
    {
        foreach (var item in _unprocessedData)
        {
            string result = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething(item));
            _processedData.Add(result);
            //NotifyPropertyChanged Collection
        }
    }

    private string DoSomething(string item)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return item;
    }
}
```

The DoSomething method can be defined in some other class outside the ViewModel.

I hope this helps.